# C# webbrowser - trigger right click

Tags: c#, javascript

I'm writing some code on Visual Studio in order to get some information from a web page.
Now I need to open the context menu of an html element and I was looking for something like that:

```
webbrowser.Navigate("javascript: document.getElementsByClassName('className')[1].rightclick();void(0);");
```

but, unfortunately, I noticed that only the click() function exists in Javascript.
Is there any workaround?

Thank you all!

Comment: do you want to open context menu on your element?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with flowing steps:

1. Get the position of the `web-browser control` on the form:

   ```
   Point controlLoc = this.PointToScreen(webBrowser1.Location);
   ```
2. Get the position your `HtmlElement` on the web-browser control

   ```
   X= element.OffsetRectangle.Left;

   Y =element.OffsetRectangle.Top;
   ```
3. Sum your positions:

   ```
   controlLoc.X = controlLoc.X + element.OffsetRectangle.Left;

   controlLoc.Y = controlLoc.Y + element.OffsetRectangle.Top;
   ```
4. Set the mouse position to new location:

   ```
   Cursor.Position = controlLoc;
   ```
5. Simulate a mouse right-click:

   ```
   MouseSimulator.ClickRightMouseButton();
   ```

**Complete Code:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<button class=\"mybtn\" type=\"submit\"> Right click";
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
        }

        void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (HtmlElement element in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button"))
            {
                if (element.GetAttribute("ClassName") == "mybtn")
                {
                    Point controlLoc = this.PointToScreen(webBrowser1.Location);
                    //Get Element Posation
                    controlLoc.X= controlLoc.X + element.OffsetRectangle.Left;
                    controlLoc.Y = controlLoc.Y + element.OffsetRectangle.Top;
                    Cursor.Position = controlLoc;
                    MouseSimulator.ClickRightMouseButton();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class MouseSimulator
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, ref INPUT pInputs, int cbSize);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct INPUT
        {
            public SendInputEventType type;
            public MouseKeybdhardwareInputUnion mkhi;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        struct MouseKeybdhardwareInputUnion
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public MouseInputData mi;

            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public KEYBDINPUT ki;

            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public HARDWAREINPUT hi;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct KEYBDINPUT
        {
            public ushort wVk;
            public ushort wScan;
            public uint dwFlags;
            public uint time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct HARDWAREINPUT
        {
            public int uMsg;
            public short wParamL;
            public short wParamH;
        }
        struct MouseInputData
        {
            public int dx;
            public int dy;
            public uint mouseData;
            public MouseEventFlags dwFlags;
            public uint time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }
        [Flags]
        enum MouseEventFlags : uint
        {
            MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001,
            MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002,
            MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004,
            MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008,
            MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010,
            MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020,
            MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x0040,
            MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN = 0x0080,
            MOUSEEVENTF_XUP = 0x0100,
            MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800,
            MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK = 0x4000,
            MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000
        }
        enum SendInputEventType : int
        {
            InputMouse,
            InputKeyboard,
            InputHardware
        }

        public static void ClickRightMouseButton()
        {
            INPUT mouseDownInput = new INPUT();
            mouseDownInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
            mouseDownInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN;
            SendInput(1, ref mouseDownInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));

            INPUT mouseUpInput = new INPUT();
            mouseUpInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
            mouseUpInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP;
            SendInput(1, ref mouseUpInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));
        }
    }
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps

**Step 1**

Create a new Windows Forms application and drag a `TextBox` and a `ContextMenuStrip` control onto the form. Set the MultiLine property of the TextBox to true and the ContextMenuStrip property to contextMenuStrip1 to override the default ContextMenu (as in the following figure) of the TextBox. See:
[image]

**Step 2**

Add six menu items in the ContextMenuStrip as in default ContextMenuStrip of the TextBox control, Undo, Cut, Copy, Paste, Delete, and "Select All" with three Separators after Undo, Delete and "Select All" menu items. Add three more menu items in the ContextMenuStrip Font, Forecolor and Backcolor for changing the font, text color and background color of the TextBox. contextMenuStrip1 should look as in the first figure above. You can refer to my previous article for adding a context menu.

Set the Name property of these menu items the same as their Text. Like for the menu item "Undo" set its Name to "Undo".

**Step 3**

Add the following code in the Opening event of contextMenuStrip1 to disable ToolStripMenuItems based on certain conditions (see comments). See:

```
private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // Disable Undo if CanUndo property returns false
    if (textBox1.CanUndo)
    {
        contextMenuStrip1.Items["Undo"].Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        contextMenuStrip1.Items["Undo"].Enabled = false;
    }


// Disable Cut, Copy and Delete if any text is not selected in TextBox
if (textBox1.SelectedText.Length == 0)
{
    contextMenuStrip1.Items["Cut"].Enabled = false;
    contextMenuStrip1.Items["Copy"].Enabled = false;
    contextMenuStrip1.Items["Delete"].Enabled = false;
}
else
{
    contextMenuStrip1.Items["Cut"].Enabled = true;
    contextMenuStrip1.Items["Copy"].Enabled = true;
    contextMenuStrip1.Items["Delete"].Enabled = true;
}

// Disable Paste if Clipboard does not contains text
if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
{
    contextMenuStrip1.Items["Paste"].Enabled = true;
}
else
{
    contextMenuStrip1.Items["Paste"].Enabled = false;
}

// Disable Select All if TextBox is blank
if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0)
{
    contextMenuStrip1.Items["SelectAll"].Enabled = false;
}
else
{
    contextMenuStrip1.Items["SelectAll"].Enabled = true;
}
```

}

**Step 4**

Add the following code in the click event of ToolStripMenuItems:

```
private void Undo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Undo();
}

private void Cut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Cut();
}

private void Copy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Copy();
}

private void Paste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Paste();
}

private void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int SelectionIndex = textBox1.SelectionStart;
    int SelectionCount = textBox1.SelectionLength;
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(SelectionIndex, SelectionCount);
    textBox1.SelectionStart = SelectionIndex;
}

private void SelectAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.SelectAll();
}

private void Font_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FontDialog fontDialog = new FontDialog();
    if (fontDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Font = fontDialog.Font;
    }
}

private void Forecolor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ColorDialog colorDialog = new ColorDialog();
    if (colorDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.ForeColor = colorDialog.Color;
    }
}

private void Backcolor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ColorDialog colorDialog = new ColorDialog();
    if (colorDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.BackColor = colorDialog.Color;
    }
}
```