# C# vb.net webbrowser - trigger right click

Tags: c#, vb.net, html-parsing

Following this example

[C# webbrowser - trigger right click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119349/c-sharp-webbrowser-trigger-right-click)

If I create an element (button) from code, it works, but if I try to open the context menu in a normal web page doesn't work
Can someone help me?

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports mshtml
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Dim Wb As New System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
    Dim str As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Size = New Size(1350, 700)
        Me.Location = New Point(10, 40)

        Wb.Size = New Size(1350, 700)
        Wb.Location = New Point(10, 10)
        Wb.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = True
        Wb.AllowWebBrowserDrop = True
        Me.Controls.Add(Wb)

        'Wb.DocumentText = "<button class=""mybtn"" type=""submit""> Right click"
        'AddHandler Wb.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted

        str = "http://google.com"

        Wb.Navigate(str)
        Do Until Wb.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop

        Dim MyHtmlElements As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection
        MyHtmlElements = Wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        Dim myHtmlElement As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection
        myHtmlElement = MyHtmlElements.GetElementsByName("btnK")

        Dim MyPoint As New Point(myHtmlElement(0).OffsetRectangle.Left + myHtmlElement(0).OffsetRectangle.Width / 2, myHtmlElement(0).OffsetRectangle.Top + myHtmlElement(0).OffsetRectangle.Height / 2)

        Dim parentElement As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement
        parentElement = myHtmlElement(0).OffsetParent
        While parentElement IsNot Nothing
            MyPoint.X += parentElement.OffsetRectangle.Left
            MyPoint.Y += parentElement.OffsetRectangle.Top
            parentElement = parentElement.OffsetParent
        End While

        Dim controlLoc As Point = Me.PointToScreen(Wb.Location)
        controlLoc.X = controlLoc.X + MyPoint.X
        controlLoc.Y = controlLoc.Y + MyPoint.Y
        Cursor.Position = controlLoc

        MouseSimulator.ClickRightMouseButton()
    End Sub

    Private Sub webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
        For Each element As HtmlElement In Wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
            If element.GetAttribute("ClassName") = "mybtn" Then
                Dim controlLoc As Point = Me.PointToScreen(Wb.Location)
                controlLoc.X = controlLoc.X + element.OffsetRectangle.Left
                controlLoc.Y = controlLoc.Y + element.OffsetRectangle.Top
                Cursor.Position = controlLoc
                MouseSimulator.ClickRightMouseButton()
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MouseSimulator
    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Shared Function SendInput(nInputs As UInteger, ByRef pInputs As INPUT, cbSize As Integer) As UInteger
    End Function

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
    Private Structure INPUT
        Public type As SendInputEventType
        Public mkhi As MouseKeybdhardwareInputUnion
    End Structure
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)>
    Private Structure MouseKeybdhardwareInputUnion
        <FieldOffset(0)>
        Public mi As MouseInputData

        <FieldOffset(0)>
        Public ki As KEYBDINPUT

        <FieldOffset(0)>
        Public hi As HARDWAREINPUT
    End Structure
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
    Private Structure KEYBDINPUT
        Public wVk As UShort
        Public wScan As UShort
        Public dwFlags As UInteger
        Public time As UInteger
        Public dwExtraInfo As IntPtr
    End Structure
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
    Private Structure HARDWAREINPUT
        Public uMsg As Integer
        Public wParamL As Short
        Public wParamH As Short
    End Structure
    Private Structure MouseInputData
        Public dx As Integer
        Public dy As Integer
        Public mouseData As UInteger
        Public dwFlags As MouseEventFlags
        Public time As UInteger
        Public dwExtraInfo As IntPtr
    End Structure
    <Flags>
    Private Enum MouseEventFlags As UInteger
        MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = &H1
        MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
        MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
        MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = &H8
        MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = &H10
        MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = &H20
        MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = &H40
        MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN = &H80
        MOUSEEVENTF_XUP = &H100
        MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = &H800
        MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK = &H4000
        MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = &H8000
    End Enum
    Private Enum SendInputEventType As Integer
        InputMouse
        InputKeyboard
        InputHardware
    End Enum

    Public Shared Sub ClickRightMouseButton()
        Dim mouseDownInput As New INPUT()
        mouseDownInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse
        mouseDownInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN
        SendInput(1, mouseDownInput, Marshal.SizeOf(New INPUT()))

        Dim mouseUpInput As New INPUT()
        mouseUpInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse
        mouseUpInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP
        SendInput(1, mouseUpInput, Marshal.SizeOf(New INPUT()))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks

After a while i found a solution.
But now i had anothe issue: **how to select contextMenu item by code?**

Thanks to everyone can help.

______ update ______

For everyone it's interested, here is a nice link to the argument.

http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.mouse_event

---

but coming back to my issue, i don't know where to find the contextMenu just created.
I don't know if is in the webBrowser, associated to htmlelement, or in the form or elsewhere.
checking the htmlElement, doesn't have contextMenu property, and the webBrowser contextMenu property it's nothing.

...

Comment: Can you explain exactly what is the problem? Or provide any error message?

Comment: the problem is that if i run the program, doesn't appear the context menu, i notice that for an instant the cursor had a redraw, but no menu appear.

Comment: Can you provide screen shot?

Comment: i tried to make a simple screenshot, and past it into Paint, but the cursor doen't appear.in the picture made, anyway, running the program appear the normal google page with the cursor over the search button, but without the context menu (right click)

Comment: i solved my first problem, but now i need to solve another problem: how to select contextMenu item by code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after checked a while i found the solution.
all the code works fine
the problem was that I had put the code in the sub form1_load:
Just finished loading the form1_load, the program redraws the form and the context menu loses focus and disappears.

But adding a button, changing the form1_load and adding a sub all works fine

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports mshtml
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Dim Wb As New System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
    Dim bStart As New Button

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Size = New Size(1350, 600)
        Me.Location = New Point(10, 40)

        bStart.Text = "go"
        bStart.Size = New Size(40, 20)
        bStart.Location = New Point(10, 10)
        AddHandler bStart.Click, AddressOf bStart_click
        Me.Controls.Add(bStart)

        Wb.Size = New Size(1350, 550)
        Wb.Location = New Point(10, 50)
        Wb.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = True
        Wb.AllowWebBrowserDrop = True
        Me.Controls.Add(Wb)

    End Sub

    Private Sub bStart_click()
        str = "http://google.com"

        Wb.Navigate(str)
        Do Until Wb.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop

        Dim HtmlActiveElements As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection
        HtmlActiveElements = Wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        Dim myHtmlElement As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection
        myHtmlElement = HtmlActiveElements.GetElementsByName("btnK")

        Dim MyPoint As New Point(myHtmlElement(0).OffsetRectangle.Left + myHtmlElement(0).OffsetRectangle.Width / 2, myHtmlElement(0).OffsetRectangle.Top + myHtmlElement(0).OffsetRectangle.Height / 2)

        Dim parentElement As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement
        parentElement = myHtmlElement(0).OffsetParent
        While parentElement IsNot Nothing
            MyPoint.X += parentElement.OffsetRectangle.Left
            MyPoint.Y += parentElement.OffsetRectangle.Top
            parentElement = parentElement.OffsetParent
        End While

        Dim controlLoc As Point = Me.PointToScreen(Wb.Location)
        controlLoc.X = controlLoc.X + MyPoint.X
        controlLoc.Y = controlLoc.Y + MyPoint.Y
        Cursor.Position = controlLoc

        MouseSimulator.ClickRightMouseButton()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: i solved my first issue, but now i need to solve another issue: how to select contextMenu item by code?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems like a little bit of overkill if you just want a custom context menu for the Webbrowser control. The code below works for me - just a basic form With a a Webbrowser control:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim Strip As New ContextMenuStrip
        Dim Item1, Item2 As ToolStripMenuItem

        Item1 = New ToolStripMenuItem("Test1", Nothing, AddressOf DoTestAction)
        Item2 = New ToolStripMenuItem("Google", Nothing, AddressOf DoGoogle)
        Strip.Items.Add(Item1)
        Strip.Items.Add(Item2)

        Me.WebBrowser1.ContextMenuStrip = Strip

    End Sub

    Public Sub DoTestAction(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show("Testing")
    End Sub

    Public Sub DoGoogle(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: sorry, seems you don't understand my question, i need to open a web page and by code perform a right click on the webbrowser button and open the context menu in the webbrowser, not in my form